# Prove a hypergeometric Identity: $\frac{\Gamma(\frac14)^2 }{8\sqrt{\pi}}\,_3F_2(.) +\frac1{2\pi}\,_3F_2(.) =\frac{\Gamma( \frac14 )^6}{32\pi^{7/2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

Are there any direct ways to prove the following relation between two $\,_3F_2$s?
$$
\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2 }{8\sqrt{\pi} } 
\,_3F_2\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac12;1,1;1 \right ) 
+\frac{1}{2\pi}\,_3F_2\left ( \frac34,\frac34,1;\frac32,\frac32;1 \right )
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^6}{32\pi^{7/2}}.
$$
The non-direct proof is based on observing the two equalities:
\begin{aligned}
&\,_4F_3\left ( \frac14,\frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,1,\frac54;-1 \right )  = \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2 }{8\sqrt{\pi} } 
\,_3F_2\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac12;1,1;1 \right ), \\
&\,_4F_3\left ( \frac14,\frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,1,\frac54;-1 \right )=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\,_3F_2\left ( \frac34,\frac34,1;\frac32,\frac32;1 \right )
+\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^6}{32\pi^{7/2}},
\end{aligned}
where the second one refers to **arXiv:1806.08411**(p16). I would appreciate it if you provide me with some ideas.

Comment: Is there any way to compute these  $\, _3F_2$ s?